# CSS Sprite menu won't display in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, menu, sprite

The company I'm working for has decided to go with a new ecommerce software and I have been re-styling the original template. I have been able to code **a CSS Sprite Menu that renders well in FF and Chrome, but does not even display in IE.** While it doesn't render in IE, it does cause gigantic spacing issues (specifically, a giant space) where the menu should be, with no images. I have been able to get the CSS validated but the HTML is automatically generated (thanks, template software!) and I haven't been able to validate it successfully.

I will admit I am not an expert coder but I have looked at and tried the solutions for different posts related to this topic on this website and others with no success. Obviously we need the website to at least display the menu on all browsers, so if you could help me troubleshoot I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here's the website so you can take a look. http://11102611542.3dcart.net/

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```
.home{}
.about{}
.industry{}
.catalog{}
.blog{}
.account{}
.contact{}

ul#topMenu{
    list-style:none;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    width:980px;
}

ul#topMenu li {display:inline;}

ul#topMenu li a{
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    background-image:url("/assets/images/menuBar/MenuFull.png");
    font-size:0px;
    /*padding:40px 0 0 0;*/
    /*margin-top:40px;*/
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    /*text-wrap:none;*/ 
    /*text-indent:-9000px;*/

    }

ul#topMenu li a.home{
    width:109px; background-position:0 0;

    }

ul#topMenu li a.about{
    width:100px; background-position:-109px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.industry{
    width:213px; background-position:-209px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.catalog{
    width:130px; background-position:-422px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.blog{
    width:86px; background-position: -552px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.account{
    width:170px; background-position: -638px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.contact{
    width:172px; background-position: -808px 0px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.home:hover{
    background-position:0 -40px;
    width:109px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.about:hover{
    width:100px; background-position:-109px -40px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.industry:hover{
    width:213px; background-position:-209px -40px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.catalog:hover{
    width:130px; background-position:-422px -40px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.blog:hover{
    width:86px; background-position: -552px -40px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.account:hover{
    width:170px; background-position: -638px -40px;
    }

ul#topMenu li a.contact:hover{
    width:172px; background-position: -808px -40px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="topMenu">
<li><a href="/home.asp" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/About-Us_ep_7.html" class="about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/Shop-By-Industry_ep_42.html" class="industry">Industry Guide</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.fusionclimb.com/flippingBook/fusion%20climb%20product%20catalog/index.html" class="catalog">Catalog</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog.asp" class="blog">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/myaccount.asp" class="account">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="/crm.asp?action=contactus" class="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can we see some code or a link to the website?

Comment: You do realize that it's impossible to troubleshoot anything you're doing without seeing the code, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and missed the "add code" formatting.

Comment: Well, you're trying, and that's a start. Welcome aboard

Comment: @bobek Thanks, I've added the website address and relevant code to the post.

Comment: You have serious, serious HTML issues.  You should fix those before anything else.  For starters, the UL element with id="topMenu" is fine, but it's contained inside a "tr" element.  There needs to be a "td" after that "tr" tag.  After the closing "tr", there are 2 more closing "tr" tags that are not connected to any opening "tr" tags.  That poor HTML code is going to be the first step to fixing your issues.

Comment: Also, you don't need for float "A" if you are already using "inline" on your LI.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It looks like I'm going to spend some quality time examining this HTML.

Comment: If you see any CSS problems (thanks @Diodeus) please point them out, but I'll validate the HTML first and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are u use too many table for layout? Add two `width="100%" height="100%"` for your two `sub-table`

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">  <-- here
<tr>
<td width="17"><img src="assets/templates/v40010/images/search_L.png" width="17" height="36" alt=""></td>
<td><input type="text" size="25" name="keyword" id="searchlight" class="search-text" onFocus="javascript:if (document.searchForm.keyword.value=='search by keyword') {document.searchForm.keyword.value='';};" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'search by keyword'" value="search by keyword"></td>
<td><input type="image" src="assets/templates/v40010/images/search_btn.png" name="search" value="GO"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<!--END: FRAME_SEARCH--></div></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">  <-- here
<tr>
<ul id="topMenu">
<li><a href="/home.asp" class="home" id="topMenu">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/About-Us_ep_7.html" class="about" id="topMenu">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/Shop-By-Industry_ep_42.html" class="industry" id="topMenu">Industry Guide</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.fusionclimb.com/flippingBook/fusion%20climb%20product%20catalog/index.html" class="catalog" id="topMenu">Catalog</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog.asp" class="blog" id="topMenu">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/myaccount.asp" class="account" id="topMenu">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="/crm.asp?action=contactus" class="contact" id="topMenu">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArNrf/) for you, test well in my ie8. And [run code](http://jsfiddle.net/ArNrf/show)

Comment: When I take the tables out (checking the tags etc) the menu doesn't display in any browser. I don't know why this template uses so many tables. I added your suggestion and it didn't make a difference, even after changing the doctype to strict.

Comment: @Ali, I use ie8, type f12, add width="100%" height="100%" into the table what I parsed and test well in my computer.  well, let me check it again for u, but it is slow to open your site for me.

Comment: @Ali, updated my answer, I update the run code in a fiddle, you can test it again. just modify `<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%"><tr><ul id="topMenu">`

Comment: I see it working in jsfiddle (in IE) but I change the HTML and I still can't see the menu in IE.. Am I doing something wrong? I'm changing the exact line you specified. (Still working on the validation, by the way)

Comment: @Ali, have you update the file to your server? when I checked the page souece in `http://11102611542.3dcart.net/`, nothing changed.

Comment: I just checked the HTML file on the server and it is updated. I don't know why IE isn't seeing the new page source-- when I view source it still prints the old code.

Comment: @Ali, maybe wait to tomorrow, the code will updated, so can you accept my answer, because my code is well, the problem is in your server, thanks and good night.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still validating (158 errors, now down to 11) but the menu shows. I'll work on the slow load next.

Answer (score 1):

I would start from scratch, I know its a pain but using template of any kind from a 3rd party software is a very bad ideal. They do not check it from browser to browser and the programmer who build that application may not be as advanced as you. My suggestion is get rid if all the tables. its very old style programming. I wish you luck

Answer (score 0):

Your website is being displayed in quriks mode in IE, that's why you can't see the menu. And the space is there because the menu is stacked instead of floated. I would suggest changing the doctype to strict, but I can see you will have problems with it since you're using 3rd party template software. If you can't change that manually, call them and tell them what the issue is.

I hope this helps.

Comment: He does not need strict doctype to avoid quirks mode... he just needs a valid doctype along with validated HTML.  This would work too:  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: I've just tried changing the doctype to both Strict and @Sparky672 s suggestion, and have not seen any changes in the display.

Comment: @Ali, did you follow my entire suggestion?  _"... along with **validated** HTML."_

Comment: @Sparky672, haha, not yet. It's going to take some major work to validate the HTML. I'm diving in now... I tried to rewrite/correct validation errors on this template earlier and they were in the hundreds. Needless to say I'm a bit intimidated.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate `id`'s, improper nesting, tags left open, etc.

You need to fix those serious HTML issues before anything else.

[http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F11102611542.3dcart.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://11102611542.3dcart.net/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)